# Implement Google Tag Manager for existing Google Analytics 4 acccount

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

I have a google analytics 4 (and google analytics 3) account for my site. I currently set it up directly (both the GA4 and GA3 account receive information from the same UA tag as I grandfathered the UA tag when setting up GA4). I want to switch it and use Tag Manager as it allows me to do more (like track custom events such as partial site scrolls). However, I do not want to lose my historic data in my GA3 and GA4 accounts - how do I set up Tag Manager to work?

I tried making a Tag Manager account but it has a different ID as my GA4 account. Worth adding: the GA4 property was created by another employee in my firm

Answer (score 1):

The ID of the GTM container has no relation to the UA or GA4 IDs.

When you make UA or GA4 tag, you have to specify the corresponding measurement ID (GA4) or property ID (UA).

You just have to carefully reimplement existing tracking in GTM, then test your GTM implementation comparing the network requests it sends to those that are now on the site. Once satisfied, publish the container and remove the obsolete implementation.

Comment: So once I replace the GA4 ID with the GTM ID, how will I transport the data from GTM to GA4? I don't want to lose my data history

Comment: In GTM, you make tags, triggers and variables to mimic your existing GA4 racking, in the tag, there is a field called Measurement ID. You have to get it from your GA4 account where you want to get the data from GTM. That's how the connection between GA4 and GTM works.